# javascript does not work in IE and Firefox after jquery 1.8.3 upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have updated to jquery 1.8.3 from jquery 1.7 (everything worked fine in all browsers), but I have installed a javascript which needs jquery 1.8.2 or 1.8.3

Now the javascript image resize on this page does not work in IE 10 and Firefox, in Chrome and Safari it resizes the image correctly.

There are no javascript errors in Firefox, so I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Offchance Did you try jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Thanks ! I have upgraded now to 1.9.1, but the problem was a table in which was the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HTML1513: Extra "`<html>`" tag found. Only one "`<html>`" tag should exist per document.
>   albert-einstein-physicist-you-have-to-learn-the-rules-of-the-game-and-then-you-have, line 9 character 5
>
> HTML1513: Extra "`<html>`" tag found. Only one "`<html>`" tag should exist per document.
>   albert-einstein-physicist-you-have-to-learn-the-rules-of-the-game-and-then-you-have, line 11 character 9
>
> HTML1517: Invalid nesting. A "`<form>`" tag should not be placed within another "`<form>`".
>   albert-einstein-physicist-you-have-to-learn-the-rules-of-the-game-and-then-you-have, line 120 character 41
>
> HTML1508: Unmatched end tag.
>   albert-einstein-physicist-you-have-to-learn-the-rules-of-the-game-and-then-you-have, line 125 character 41
>
> HTML1409: Invalid attribute name character. Attribute names should not contain ("),('),(<), or (=).
>   albert-einstein-physicist-you-have-to-learn-the-rules-of-the-game-and-then-you-have, line 249 character 55

These probably don't help. But anyway, it looks like all you need to do is change the `max-width/min-width` properties on the image to just `width:100%`.

Comment: I have changed the width from 850px to 100%, but still the same problem.

Comment: Ok, I have solved the problem, I got rid of the table in which was the image, and now it looks ok. I still have to cleanup the html. Thanks!